# Unable to import binding ‘Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerBinding’ from namespace ‘urn:Magento’ for magento integration

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0

We are getting error when we take webreference. The error is

Unable to import binding ‘Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerBinding’ from namespace ‘urn:Magento’

Please help us out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We execute below url in command prompt which is run by Administrator

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin>wsdl.exe /language:cs /out:MagentoService.cs /n:MagentoService http://domain.com/magento16/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl

and We set WS-i Compliance to YES (you need to go to Magento BackEnd on the System / Configuration /Core Api)

after this it has been created proxy class then we update web reference, it will execute without error. We accessed webservice by calling objects

We used magento 1.6.2.0 version. It will give same error for magento version 1.7.0

Regards

Sangamesh Arali